# Export PATH using NET::SSH:PERL

Tags: perl, export, perlnetssh

I am writing a shell script to automate some of the tedious tasks that we perform. I need to ssh to a server and change the PATH variable remotely, have that variable persist for the next commands to be executed. Code below;

```
sub ab_tier{
 my $ssh=Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
 $ssh->login($user2,$user2);
 my $PATH;
 my($stdout,$stderr,$exit)=$ssh->cmd("export
 PATH=/usr/bin/sudo:/local/perl-5.6.1/bin:$PATH");
 my($PATH, $stderr, $exit)=$ssh->cmd("echo $PATH");
 print $PATH; # Check the path for correctness : does not change 
}
```

However the PATH does not change. Is there another way to implement this or am I doing something wrong. I need to automate tasks so dont think $ssh->shell would help here. Please suggest.

---

I made changes as per suggestions and everything works fine. However I am noticing another issue, which is occurring when trying to display environment variables.

```
  my $cmd_ref_pri={
    cmd0=>"echo $ENV{'HOME'}",
    cmd1=>"chmod 777 $ENV{'COMMON_TOP'}/temp"
  };
```

Now I am connecting to a remote server using Net::SSH::Perl and the value returned by $ENV{"HOME"} is the value of the my home directory and not of the remote server. However if I add a command as in :

```
    my $cmd_ref_pri={
       cmd0=>"whoami ; echo $ENV{'HOME'}",
       cmd1=>"chmod 777 $ENV{'COMMON_TOP'}/temp"
     };
```

Then the user id displayed is of the user using which I ssh to the remote server. I do not have other modules installed and the only one available is Net:SSh:perl hence I am forced to use this.

routine for executing command

```
    sub ssh_cmd{
       #$cmd_sub - contains command, $ssh contains object ref
       my ($cmd_sub,$ssh)=@_;
       my($stdout, $stderr, $exit)=$ssh->cmd("bash",$cmd_sub);
       if( $exit !=0){
       print $stdout;
       print  "ERROR-> $stderr";
       exit 1;
     }
    return 0;
   }
```

Any suggestions as to why this could happen ?

Comment: $PATH is being expanded by perl, you have to escape it: `my($PATH, $stderr, $exit)=$ssh->cmd("echo \$PATH");` (though, that will not solve your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd()` is not passing your commands into one shell. It executes them in separate shells (or without any shell - manual is not clear about it). As soon as you finish your `export PATH` the shell exits and the new PATH is lost.

Looks like it is possible to pass all the relevant commands to a single shell process as separate lines of $stdin?

```
my $stdin='export A=B
echo $A
';
$ssh->cmd("bash",$stdin);
```

This would work just like on interactive login (but without terminal control, so commands that talk directly to terminal would likely fail).

Anyway Net::SSH::Perl does not look like the best tool for the job. I would rather use `expect` for automation.

Answer (score 1):

Set PATH on every command call:

```
$ssh->cmd('PATH=/usr/bin/sudo:/local/perl-5.6.1/bin:$PATH echo $PATH');
```

And BTW, Net::SSH::Perl is not being maintained anymore, nowadays [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2) and [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) are better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Write commands to a remote temp file, then execute that one. Or, skip the $PATH thing and use the full path for subsequent commands (assuming you know it).